# Pass named function to an events map

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor template that includes the following:

```
{{#with selected_recipe}}
  {{>recipe}}
{{/with}}
```

In my code (Coffeescript), I want to call a function by name from my event map (Backbone-style):

```
Template.recipe.events = {
  'click #btn-edit-recipe': 'editRecipe'
}

editRecipe = (event) ->
  console.log @  #should log the selected_recipe object
  #edit recipe
```

However, this fails. When I click on my button in the recipe template, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object editRecipe has no method 'call' (liveui.js:651)` I learned event maps from Backbone, and maybe Meteor is different. I can get it to work with:

```
Template.recipe.events = {
  'click #btn-edit-recipe': -> editRecipe.call(@, event)
}
```

Is this the right way to do this? Or am I making some simple error? I've always liked using event maps this way because it summarizes the behaviors of the rendered template in just a few lines. Anonymous functions can spread the list out, making it harder to read, and of course they are not reusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing (later one, where event definition points to a function) is right.
Event map with value as function name (string) is pattern specific to backbone. Meteor doesn't support it.

> I've always liked using event maps this way because it summarizes the
>   behaviors of the rendered template in just a few lines.

But you can acheive similar functionality by doing something like this:

```
Template.recipe.doLogin = function(){};
Template.recipe.requestData = function(){};

//  OR Another way
_.extend(Template.recipe, {
    "openFile":function(){},
    "editRecipe":function(){} 
});

//  now Events
Template.recipe.events {
    'click #btn-edit-recipe': Template.recipe['editRecipe'],
    'click #btn-create-recipe': Template.recipe['createRecipe']
}
```

Personally, I don't like event-maps. cause its a mapping, which developer has to maintain manually. 
**Edit:** Working code @ https://gist.github.com/3010818

Comment: Thanks for the response, Nachiket. I tried your event map, and Meteor won't do that either (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined (liveui.js:651)` despite the fact that I can call `Template.recipe['editRecipe']()` successfully from the console. For the time being, I'm sticking with calling my function from within the anonymous function. Do you think this is a bug in Meteor?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put all of that together. I have tried the gist code. It works, and running through it helped me solve my problem. As it turns out, my `Template.recipe.events` object was declared before my `editRecipe` function. Javascript kindly crashes and makes you find the error. With Coffeescript, for some reason, it compiles and runs but fails since the function named is undefined at the time it is assigned. I guess my `-> editRecipe.call(@, event)` gave it function scope so it would bind when called. This got me thinking a little deeper on scope and hoisting. Thanks!