# Meteor event maps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I like Meteor's "event map" approach (http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps) for organizing UI event handlers, and was wondering if this or similar is available as a third-party plugin for use outside of Meteor?

Example:

```
Template.login.events = {
  // Fires when any element is clicked
  'click': function (event) { ... },

  // Fires when any element with the 'accept' class is clicked
  'click .accept': function (event) { ... },

  // Fires when 'accept' is clicked, or a key is pressed
  'keydown, click .accept': function (event) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like jQuery supports very similar syntax:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('.link').on({
  click: function() {
    t.find('div').show();
  },
  mouseout: function() {
    t.find('div').hide();
  }
});
```

Seems good enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer on this question:
[Pass named function to an events map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198734/pass-named-function-to-an-events-map/11206039#11206039)

It is exactly what you have asked.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm asking about using event maps without using Meteor.  I'd like to know if there's a plugin or simple way to register DOM events on selectors, without Meteor

Comment: aah, my bad, not removing this answer, keeping it for reference.